# Sencha Cmd Fails to Generate app in certain directories

Tags: windows, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am using Sencha Cmd v3.1.0.239 on windows 7 and am trying to get down the basics of creating an extJS application. Currently I have run into a strange problem where it cannot build the application depending on the target directory I specify.

In one case I will run a command like `sencha generate app myApp1 "C:\extJS experiments\myApp1"` and this **will work**. However I will run another command such as `sencha generate app myApp2 C:\xampp\htdocs\senchaWork\extJS\myApp2` and it **will fail** with the following error

> [ERR] Theme ext-theme-classic not found
>
> [ERR]
>
> [ERR] BUILD FAILED
>
> [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Required packages not found
>
> [ERR]
>
> [ERR] Total time: 3 seconds
>
> [ERR]com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Required packages not found

All I have been able to find online related to this seems to point to upgrading sencha command to be the cause. Problem with that theory is that this is the first time I have downloaded sencha command so no upgrade was ever done.

Note: In the above commands I am in the extJS sdk directory so I don't specify it. When I do specify the location of the sdk I get the same behavior as above. Shouldn't my target dir not matter since Sencha cmd is getting the ext-theme-classic from the sdk in the first place or do I mis-understand how the command works?

Comment: Where is your Sencha source tree located?

Comment: @sha my ExtJS source tree is located at C:\xampp\htdocs\senchawork\ext-4.2.1.883\src

Comment: You need to check project and index files for both projects to see what's the difference. And ideally to post them here so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Executing `sencha generate app` requires to be run on the `ExtJS` sdk directory. If this is not executed on the sdk folder, you have to specify the sdk folder by adding the `-sdk` option so that it will be able to correctly map where your sdk is.

Example:

```
sencha -sdk /path/of/my/sdk/extjs/ generate app myAppName /path/of/myApp
```

For [sencha-cmd](/questions/tagged/sencha-cmd) options and details, you can execute:

```
sencha
```